# React state hooks and useEffect unexpected behavior for state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a project I did before in Vue and now am doing in React(w/ hooks) in order to learn it. I'm having a few problems and concerns that I'm not going about it the right way(certain I'm not).

One of the biggest problems I'm having is where the state is updated via onchange and onblur. Many times the state values would be one "tick" behind. I found that with old class components you could use a callback within setState.
I'm trying to make instant form validation feedback show/hide as the user updates the fields.

With hooks, it is supposed to be done with useEffect. I have it "working" right now but it seems it's rendering more times than it should. I can tell by the fact it runs the checkValues() twice to show the current state values .

An example of the nature of my misunderstanding is if I don't put    `setinValid(validateForm());` within the onchange AND the useEffect.. it won't update the state for inValid which disables/enables the submit button. This seems redundant to me and I'm not sure why it "works" as is.

Any help/insight on how to properly do what I'm attempting would be greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/user-listing-in-react-9ip4t?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FUser%2FUserAdd.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import { saveUserToLocalStorage } from "../../utils/StorageHelper";
// import { User } from "../../utils/UserClass";

const UserAdd = props => {
  const [userName, setuserName] = React.useState("");
  const [userAge, setuserAge] = React.useState("");
  const [userEmail, setuserEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [inValid, setinValid] = React.useState(true);
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({
    name: [],
    age: [],
    email: []
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkValues();
    setinValid(validateForm());
  }, [userName, userAge, userEmail, inValid]);
  const validateForm = () => {
    if (isNaN(userAge)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!userName || !userAge || !userEmail) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!validateEmail(userEmail)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  function checkIndividualErrors() {
    if (userName.length === 0) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, name: ["User name is required"] });
    } else {
      setErrors({ ...errors, name: [] });
    }
  }
  const checkValues = () => {
    console.log(
      "username:",
      userName,
      "age:",
      userAge,
      "useremail: ",
      userEmail,
      "invalid:",
      inValid
    );
  };
  const validateEmail = mail => {
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 class="line-container">
        <span>Add a new User</span>
      </h2>
      <hr />
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <p class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={userName}
                onChange={e => {
                  setuserName(e.target.value);
                  setinValid(validateForm());
                  checkIndividualErrors();
                }}
                onBlur={checkIndividualErrors}
              />

              <span class="error">{errors.name}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Age</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <p class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="text"
                name="age"
                placeholder="Age"
                value={userAge}
                onChange={e => {
                  setuserAge(e.target.value);
                  setinValid(validateForm());
                  // checkIndividualErrors not fully implemented yet
                }}
              />
              <span class="error" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <p class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                value={userEmail}
                onChange={e => {
                  setuserEmail(e.target.value);
                  setinValid(validateForm());
                  // checkIndividualErrors not fully implemented yet
                }}
              />
              <span class="error" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="" style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
        <button
          disabled={inValid}
          class="button is-primary"
          style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}
        >
          Create
        </button>
        <Link to="/" class="button">
          Cancel
        </Link>
        <Link to="/" class="goBack">
          <span style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>←</span>
        </Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default UserAdd;
```

Comment: Without checking through the nuts & bolts of what is quite an overcomplicated component, I can tell you that you're "lying" to useEffect about its dependencies which should include the functions called within it (checkValues, setinValid, validateForm). Rendering too often is a symptom of incorrect dependencies. However you should also consider simplifying your code by destructuring, decomposition into smaller components and collapsing of state (all those useStates should probably be replaced with a single useState managing an object containing the pieces of form data & flags).

Comment: Thanks but..I understand and expected to refactor to minimal code (form state to one object, form broken into sub components etc..) but I wanted to make a decent MVP first. I knew I was most likely mis-using useEffect but your comment doesn't help me know why. I knew it was attempting to render too much but couldn't see why.

Comment: This excellent article by Dan Abramov is very long and can't/shouldn't be adequately paraphrased here, but explains very well what's going on with useEffect. https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Do you want the errors to appear while typing or only when the field blurs?

Comment: @cbdev420 both onclick and blur